# Firebug reference error that one of my functions is not defined when it's called from the KineticJS library

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm using the KineticJS library to draw some images to the canvas, and make them draggable. I've downloaded a copy of the library, so that I can make one or two slight adjustments to it, in order to use it with the canvas game I'm making.

The function within the KineticJS library that I've altered is the

```
drawHit: function(){}
```

Originally, the function looked like this:

```
drawHit: function() {
    this.hitCanvas.clear();
    Kinetic.Container.prototype.drawHit.call(this);
},
```

But I've added in a couple of calls to functions that I've written:

```
drawHit: function() {
    this.hitCanvas.clear();
    drawGameElements();
    drawDescriptionBoxes(imageObj);
    Kinetic.Container.prototype.drawHit.call(this);
},
```

The reason I've done this, is because beforehand, when dragging and dropping an image around the canvas, the canvas would be completely cleared when a click was detected, and only the images would be redrawn- I had a few other things displayed on the canvas that I wanted to remain there each time the canvas was redrawn when moving an image around. (These things were drawn by the two function calls I've added to this function)

However, when I view my page in a browser now, I'm getting the Firebug console error:

```
ReferenceError: drawDescriptionBoxes is not defined

drawDescriptionBoxes(imageObj);
```

on the line

```
drawDescriptionBoxes(imageObj);
```

(where I've added it to the function)

The function 'drawDescriptionBoxes' is defined in a file called 'drawdescriptionboxes.js' and has the following code:

```
function drawDescriptionBoxes(imageObj){
/*  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawDescriptionArea = function(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke){
        if(typeof stroke == "undefined" ){
            stroke = true;
        }
        if(typeof radius === "undefined"){
            radius = 5;
        }
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        this.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
        this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
        this.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
        this.lineTo(x, y + radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        this.closePath();
        if(stroke){
            context.stroke();
        }
    } */
    var assetsDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 70,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });

    var liabilitiesDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 300,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });

    var incomeDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 540,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });

    var expenditureDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 750,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });

}
```

I am calling this function from the

```
window.onload = function(){}
```

in my index.html page with the line

```
drawdescriptionboxes();
```

I have another couple of functions also being called here in exactly the same way, and there is no problem with them.

Anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this reference error?

**Edit**

I'm also getting a syntax error: missing } after property list on line 30 of drawDescriptionBoxes.js:

```
function drawDescriptionBoxes(imageObj){
/*  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawDescriptionArea = function(x, y, width, height, radius, stroke){
        if(typeof stroke == "undefined" ){
            stroke = true;
        }
        if(typeof radius === "undefined"){
            radius = 5;
        }
        this.beginPath();
        this.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        this.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
        this.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - radius, y + height);
        this.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
        this.lineTo(x, y + radius);
        this.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        this.closePath();
        if(stroke){
            context.stroke();
        }
    } */
    var assetsDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 70,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });

    var liabilitiesDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 300,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });

    var incomeDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 540,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });

    var expenditureDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 750,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });

    context.drawImage(sources[34], 70, 400, 120, 70);
    context.drawImage(sources[35], 300, 400, 120, 70);
    context.drawImage(sources[36], 540, 400, 120, 70);
    context.drawImage(sources[37], 750, 400, 120, 70);

}
```

Line 30 is the line:

```
draggable: false
```

in

```
var assetsDescriptionBoxImage = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: imageObj,
        width: 120,
        height: 70,
        x: 70,
        y: 400
        draggable: false
    });
```

so I don't know if this is what would be causing the other error?

Comment: Your error on line 30 is you forgot to put a comma after the 400 on the previous line.  It should be `y: 400,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `developer tools` in Chrome or `firebug` in firefox (F12) set a break point in your script and follow the function calls step by step and make sure your library is included and called (function is defined) before you call it.

You should try copy/paste your function definition `drawdescriptionboxes` just before calling it first time, once it works fine, you should place it in a place where the function definition gets called before the function call.

Comment: My function definition for `drawdescriptionboxes` is in a separate file to where I call it- surely I don't need to paste the definition where I call it as well do I?

Comment: Ok then if it is in another file you should make sure you are including your file before calling your function, and yes you can include as I mentioned just for testing and debugging purposes, once you make sure that is the problem then you fix it and you take the code out.

Comment: I am including the all of the JS files I'm using in my HTML page, with lines like: `<script src="drawdescriptionboxes.js"></script>`. It's complaining that 'drawdescriptionboxes is not defined in the kinetic.js library... I've saved a copy of the library locally, to add a call to that function in the library, and am using the version I've saved locally, rather than the one that's available online. Surely I don't need to include my JS file in the KineticJS library I've downloaded and modified to ensure that it knows about it?

Comment: If they're both included in my HTML, they should know about each other right?

Comment: as I told you in general in a scripting language in order to call a function it should be previously defined.
in your case make sure you are including your library and your are defining your function before calling it.